# How to get correct daylight saving time abbreviation

Tags: ios, swift

I am in the UK and our current timezone abbreviation is BST (which is the daylight saving time version of GMT). I use `TimeZone.current.abbreviation()` to get the abbreviation, but it returns "GMT+1" instead of "BST". How can I make it show the correct abbreviation?

Update, I seem to have done it by doing this: Can anyone see any problems with this?

```
let value = TimeZone.abbreviationDictionary.filter { $0.value == TimeZone.current.identifier }.keys.first
let abbreviation = value ?? TimeZone.current.abbreviation()
print(abbreviation) // Returns BST
```

Comment: The mapping between abbreviations and timezone identifiers is not one-to-one. One identifier can have multiple abbreviations. Are you aware of this, and what do you want to do in when multiple possible abbreviations exist?

Comment: @Sweeper I wasn't aware of that. I'm not really sure about other countries but I just want it to choose the "most appropriate one", especially in regards to daylight saving times. So in the UK in summer I'd expect it to choose BST, in winter GMT. I just don't want it to have something with additional hours like "TimezoneAbbreviation+1"

Comment: @Sweeper On the description for the `abbreviation()` func it says "Note that the abbreviation may be different at different dates. For example, during daylight saving time the US/Eastern time zone has an abbreviation of “EDT.” At other times, its abbreviation is “EST.” I thought this would mean it would choose BST.